# Is it compulsory to write an Alert Dialog open code inside an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

i All,
I have a MapActivity class which extends Activity and an associated class called MapRenderer as class in a different package.
(On seeing the stack on debugging, it can be seen that the control does pass from MapActivity to MapRenderer)
On one particular application input action i.e. when the user touches the screen, i need to pop up an android dialog. The code that governs this action is present in the class  MapRenderer (which does not extend any class) and the method resembles.

```
class MapRenderer{
public void drawRoute(Canvas canvas,String routeName) {

if(condition 0){
//Do 0 related stuff
}

if(condition N){
//Do N related stuff
// I need to implement the alert dialog at this place
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder1.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
}

if(condition inbetween){
//Do inbetween related stuff
}

}
}
```

But this seems to give out an error if i try to call a dialog from a class (in this case 'MapRenderer') that does not implement Activity.
Can you please confirm that actions like AlertDialog popup require such code as seen sbove to be written only in a class that extends
Activity ?

Comment: where do you set the `context` variable?

Comment: I tried setting the context using an Application wide context which is available in a static variable with value getApplicationContext(). I got the error "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application”  .No activities were visible inside this method hence i could not use MyActivity.this etc..

Answer (score 1):

No it is not true, as long as the `context` object you use to create the `Dialog` is valid and belongs to the `Activity`. I usually pass the `Activity` as parameter to my helper method and before call `dialog.show()` I check for `activity.isFinishing()`

Answer (score 0):

You can write it anywhere you want. Just keep in mind that at runtime it needs an Activity to display itself. so the context you passed to the builder must be the one with an Activity.